# If I lose access to my account after enabling two factor authentication, will I lose my entire developer account?

Tags: apple-id, developer-program, two-factor-authentication

Today I enabled two-factor-authentication for my Apple ID since they required me to do so.

Before finishing the process, a message popped up, saying:

> Apple will not be able to reset your password on your behalf.

Now, I'm a bit scared that if I lose access to my phone AND my recovery key for whatever reason - will I lose my entire developer account without any chance of recovery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [Apple Developer Two-Factor Authentication FAQ's](https://developer.apple.com/support/account/authentication/?cid=2fa-e-en-001):

> ### What if I lose access to my trusted devices and trusted phone number?
>
> You can request [account recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204921) to regain access to your account.
>
> Account recovery might take a few days or longer, depending on the specific account information you can provide to verify your identity.

Comment: Thank you! The message from apple just made me a bit sceptical.